# Windows で docker-compose での runコマンドが実行できない。（-dオプションを進められる）

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

[Quickstart: Docker Compose and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)

上記チュートリアルの通り進めていく中で、

```
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
```

を実行すると

```
Please pass the -d flag when using 'docker-compose run'
```

と表示されます。

Windows 10
Docker v1.11.0
docker-compose v1.7.0

同じような手順をmacbookでは問題なく実行できたのですが、何が問題かわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

もしくは自分のWindows環境では、問題なかったよという方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決っぽいので一応投稿します。 間違ってたら指摘お願いします。

> Take a look here: https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1655be6c5bcbc35d2a34bd4c464b8a91981aaa42/compose/cli/main.py#L550

で

```
        if IS_WINDOWS_PLATFORM and not detach:
        raise UserError(
            "Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows.\n"
            "Please pass the -d flag when using `docker-compose run`."
        )
```

ウィンドウズではインタラクティブモードはまだサポートされてないってありました。
とりあえず、別の方法で考えてみます。